# If two matrices have same characteristic polynomial, then if square root for one exists, it also exists for the other one.

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial

This is True/False question from the recent exam.

Statement: Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two elements of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that their characteristic polynomials are equal. If $A=C^2$ for some $C\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, then $B=D^2$ for some $D\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

I haven't reach the conclusion yet. But here's my thought. Since $A=C^2$, eigenvalues of $A$ are non-negative. Since $C_A(x)=C_B(x)$, eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are same, which means $B$ also have non-negative eigenvalues. But will this guarantee square root for $B$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be false. As an easy example, take a $2\times2$-Jordan block with Eigenvalue $0$. This matrix does not have a square root, but it has the same characteristic polynomial as the zero-matrix which obviuosly has a square root.

Comment: Is there any easy way to show that Jordan block of $0$ does not admit a square root. I proved it by considering a general square of a $2 \times 2$ matrix, which gave four equations and which lead to some contradiction.

Comment: Also may I know how you came up with this example. I was thinking a lot about such counterexample!

Comment: I came up with the example when I gave this as an exercise a long time ago. As a general rule of thumb: You should always look for counter-examples in Jordan Normal Form. (and if your field is algebraically closed then you do not even love generality)

Comment: The shortest way to see that the Jordan block B does not have a square root is Cayley-Hamilton. If it had a square root R, then R^2=B and so R^4=0 and therefore the minimal polynomial of R divides X^4. By Cayley-Hamilton it has to be a divisor of X^2, so we may assume R^2=0 which implies B=0 which is false.

Comment: Just loved this argument. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

Consider the two matrices
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix}
B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
they have the same characteristic polynomials,$A$ has a square root, but $B$ doesn't have a square root. $$ $$
Edit:this is too long for a comment:
@Believer :for the first question,there is a general fact in Linear algebra if two linear $X,Y$ commute ,$E$ is an invariant subspace of $X$, (i.e $XE\subset E$),then $YE$ is an invariant subspace of $X$(i.e $X(YE)\subset YE$).Now if $B=D^{2}$,then $B$ and $D$ commute (bacause $B$ is a polynomial in $B$),since $<e_{1}>$ is the only (nontrivial)invariant subspace of $B$,$e_{1}$ must be an eigenvector of $D$,in particular $D$ must be upper triangular,with both diagonal values equal zero,but u can check that in thi scase $D^{2}=0$,so it cannot be equal to $B$
an easier way to see this is that if $D^{2}=B$,then $D$ is nilpotent,but we know that index of nilpotency is always lower or equal to the dimension, so again $D^{2}=0$,So $B$ doesn't have a square root.

Comment: Sir is there any easy way to claim $B$ doesn't have a square root?

Comment: Also it will be helpful for me if you share how you came up with this. Thanks.

Comment: @Believer I edited my answer with two  proofs of the non-existence of the square root.

Comment: For the second question,the general idea is that the caracterestic polynomial doesn't tell a lot about non-diagonalizable matrices ,it only captures the algebraic multplicity,So it cannot diferenciate between nilpotent matrices having different nilpotency idices for example (thoug the nilpotency index itself is not sufficient to determine the conjugacy class of the nilpotent matrix),if $n$ is the dimension of the spaces,then all the nilpotent matrices have caracterestic polynomial $x^{n}$.

Comment: Thank you sir..